# C programs compiled with GCC causing NVTDM errors when .exes are run on Windows 7 32 bit

Tags: c, windows, gcc, windows-7

I am attempting to get GCC/G++ running on a 32 bit Windows 7 machine, installed via Cygwin. I can compile and link my basic "Hello World" program just fine, but when I try to run it, I get a "NVTDM.EXE has stoppped working" error.

I have been googling for the last hour or so, and all I can find is a bunch of references to the fact that NTVDM is supposed to run old 16 bit legacy code, and apparently a Windows XP patch broke it.

I have tried using the -m32 compiler tag to force compilation in 32 bit code, and compiled using both the 32 bit GCC/MinGW executables, and the 64 bit ones just out of curiosity, and I get the same NVTDM error every time. Any ideas on what is going wrong?

**Source Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Base GCC compile line used:

```
gcc -Wall -c HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld.exe
```

Error Details:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name: ntvdm.exe
Application Version: 6.1.7600.16385
Application Timestamp: 4a5bc158
Fault Module Name: StackHash_2264
Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset: 00000229
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID: 1033
Additional Information 1: 2264
Additional Information 2: 2264db07e74365624c50317d7b856ae9
Additional Information 3: 875f
Additional Information 4: 875fa2ef9d2bdca96466e8af55d1ae6e
```

Comment: remove `-c` option E.g `gcc -Wall HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld.exe`

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you installed GCC through Cygwin and calling it as `gcc`, you're not compiling MinGW/native executables, but rather Cygwin executables. If you want non-Cygwin executables, you'll need to install and call `{i686,x86_64}-w64-mingw32-gcc`.

The runtime crash seems quite mysterious, but it might be due to a missing Cygwin DLL (which of course is required for Cygwin applications. But that's not what you want, so try the above.

Comment: Interestingly, I tried all the variations on the mingw and gcc executables such as: i686-pc-cygwin-gcc, i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-4.9.3, i686-pc-mingw32-gcc, i686-pc-mingw32-gcc-4.7.3, i686-w64-mingw32-gcc, i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.9.2 and their 64 bit versions just for the hell of it. All of them replicated the same error.